# How to make a window background completely transparent?

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I want to run a gif on pyglet where the background is completely transparent so only the shape of the gif will be on the screen and on the background will be whatever screen is already when the program is executed, is there any way to do that?

```
from threading import *
import time
import pyglet


class Gif(Thread):

    def run(self):
        animation = pyglet.image.load_animation("gif3.gif")
        animSprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)
        animSprite.opacity = 200

        w = animSprite.width
        h = animSprite.height

        window = pyglet.window.Window(width=w, height=h, 
                 style=pyglet.window.Window.WINDOW_STYLE_BORDERLESS)
        platform = pyglet.window.get_platform()
        display = platform.get_default_display()
        screen = display.get_default_screen()
        pyglet.gl.glEnable(pyglet.gl.GL_BLEND)
        pyglet.gl.glBlendFunc(pyglet.gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, pyglet.gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)


        window.set_location((screen.width-w)//2, (screen.height-h)//2)
        # r,g,b,alpha = 1, 1, 1, 1
        # pyglet.gl.glClearColor(r,g,b,alpha)

        @window.event
           def on_draw():
              window.clear()
              animSprite.draw()
        pyglet.app.run()

gif = Gif()
gif.daemon = True

gif.start()

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(2)
```

I always get the background either black or white.

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved with Pyglet or native GL. This is the compositing managers job (Like [Compiz](http://www.compiz.org/) for instance) together with your window manager (if you're on linux that is). If you're on windows, you'll have to call `ctypes.windll.user32` and call this function (among others): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes

Comment: Another note is that you *probably* *(most definitely)* don't want to use threads with your graphics classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I only "develop" for hobby, so my knowledge is quite limited. I've got the way to do it on tkinter, but the speed is really slow, do you know any other package to run a gif with a transparent background? Notice that I don't want to apply a transparent window, because my Gif already has it.

Comment: For the second comment, I was just understanding how threads work and I thought i was a good idea, so it could be as a program which, when doing its tasks, executes a gif.

Answer (score 0):

In line `window = pyglet.window.Window(width=w, height=h, style=pyglet.window.Window.WINDOW_STYLE_BORDERLESS)` just replace `pyglet.window.Window.WINDOW_STYLE_BORDERLESS` to `'transparent'` or `'overlay'`.